# Retrieving all fields vs only some in graphql, Time Comparison

Tags: graphql

I am currently working on a project involving graphQL and I was wondering if the action of retrieving every elements of a given type in a query was taking significantly more time than only retrieving some or if this time was negligible.

Here is an exemple:

```
fragment GlobalProtocolStatsFields on GlobalProtocolStats {
totalProfiles
totalBurntProfiles
totalPosts
totalMirrors
totalComments
totalCollects
totalFollows
totalRevenue {
    ...Erc20AmountFields
}}
```

vs

```
fragment GlobalProtocolStatsFields on GlobalProtocolStats {
totalProfiles
totalBurntProfiles
totalPosts
totalMirrors
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer highly depends on the implementation on the backend side. Let's look at what three stages the data goes through and how this can impact response time.

### 1. Data fetching from the source

First, the GraphQL server has to fetch the data from the database or a different data source. Some data sources allow you to specify which fields you want to receive. If the GraphQL service is optimised to only fetch the data needed, some time can be saved here. In my experience, it is often not worth it to do this and it is much easier to just fetch all fields that could be needed for an object type. Some GraphQL implementations do this automatically, e.g. Hasure, Postgraphile, Pothos with the Prisma Plugin. What can be more expensive is resolving relationships between entities. Often, the GraphQL implementation has to do another roundtrip to the server.

### 2. Data transformation and business logic

Sometimes, the data has to be transformed before it is returned from the resolver. The resolver model allows this business logic to be called conditionally. Leaving out a field will skip its resolver. In my experience, most business logic is incredibly fast and does not really impact response time.

### 3. Data serialisation and network

Once all the data is ready on the server side, it has to be serialised to JSON and sent to the client. Serializing large amounts of data can be expensive, especially because GraphQL is hard to serialise in a stream. Sending data to the client can also take a while, if the connection is slow or the data has a large size. This was one of the motivations for GraphQL: Allow the client to select the required fields and reduce unused data transfer.

### Summary

As you can see, the response time is mostly related to the amount of data returned from the API and the network connection. Depending on the implementation, real savings are only made on the network, but more advanced implementations can drastically reduce the work done on the server as well.